# Separate roles/permissions if user belongs to many organizations

Tags: laravel, laravel-permission

I have an application where a user can belong to multiple organizations. I want to set it up in a way that a user can have different roles/permissions for each organization. I am using Laravel and plan on implementing Spatie/laravel-permission. What is the best way to implement this?

I have tried setting up two guards, one for the main user account and another for the pivot model between the user and the organization they log into. So basically when they log into the app using the main user model, I ask them which organization they would like to log into, when they choose the organization I will then also set up an auth session on the pivot model that links the user to the organization and access the roles off that model. This works, but having to manage the auth sessions is kind of a pain.

```
// User Model
class User extends Authenticatable
{
    public function organizationUsers()
    {
        return $this->hasMany(OrganizationUser::class);
    }
}
```

```
// OrganizationUser Model

class Organziationuser extends Authenticatable
{
    use HasRoles;

    public $guard_name = 'organization_user';

    public function organization()
    {
        return $this->belongsTo(Organization::class);
    }

    public function user()
    {
        return $this->belongsTo(User::class);
    }
}
```

I would expect a user to be able to log into the application using a single login, but also be able to have different permissions for different organizations.

Comment: Spatie Laravel permission is well made but cannot respond to all use cases. You should consider implementing you own role/permission system. It's not that hard once you dig in and gives your more flexibility.

Comment: I wonder if adding an organization_id to the model_has_roles and model_has_permissions table would be the ticket. Then I should be able to filter on that organization_id to get the roles and permissions for the user model. Hmm..

Comment: You can try, but consider this: The basis of the package is to assign roles/permissions and check roles/permissions. By adding an organization_id, you cannot assign nor check through the package. You need to do it yourself. The only thing in the package that's left to you is the caching and a base for the model/migration. In my opinion It's a good thing to not be over-dependent of packages. Especially when they do not fill the expected behavior.

Answer (score 0):

I have got around this issue by doing the following. I would welcome feedback on peoples views of this method!

Note: Currently I am only using the `model_has_roles` table with Spatie permissions and always use `$user->can('Permission')` to check permissions.

1. Our company model has the following relationships and method

```
class Company extends Model
{
    public function owner(): HasOne
    {
        return $this->hasOne(User::class, 'id', 'user_id');
    }

    public function users(): BelongsToMany
    {
        return $this->belongsToMany(
            User::class, 'company_users', 'company_id', 'user_id'
        )->using(CompanyUser::class);
    }

    public function addTeamMember(User $user)
    {
        $this->users()->detach($user);

        $this->users()->attach($user);
    }
}
```

2. We modify the pivot model to have the Spatie `HasRoles` trait. This allows us to assign a role to the `CompanyUser` as opposed to the Auth User. You also need to specify the default guard or Spatie permissions squarks.

```
class CompanyUser extends Pivot
{
    use HasRoles;

    protected $guard_name = 'web';
}
```

3. On the user model, I have created the `HasCompanies` Trait. This provides the relationships and provides a method for assigning the roles to the new company user. Additionally, it overwrites the gate `can()` method.

A user can belong to many companies, but can only have one active company at a time (i.e. the one they are viewing). We define this with the `current_company_id` column.

It is also important to ensure the pivot table ID is pulled across (which it will not be as standard) as this is now what we are using in the Spatie `model_has_roles table`.

```
trait HasCompanies
{
    public function companies(): HasMany
    {
        return $this->hasMany(Company::class);
    }

    public function currentCompany(): HasOne
    {
        return $this->hasOne(Company::class, 'id', 'current_company_id');
    }

    public function teams(): BelongsToMany
    {
        return $this->belongsToMany(
            Company::class, 'company_users', 'user_id', 'company_id'
        )->using(CompanyUser::class)->withPivot('id');
    }

    public function switchCompanies(Company $company): void
    {
        $this->current_company_id = $company->id;
        $this->save();
    }

    public function assignRolesForCompany(Company $company, ...$roles)
    {
        if($company = $this->teams()->where('companies.id', $company->id)->first()){
            /** @var CompanyUser $companyUser */
            $companyUser = $company->pivot;
            $companyUser->assignRole($roles);
            return;
        }

        throw new Exception('Roles could not be assigned to company user');
    }

    public function can($ability, $arguments = [])
    {
        if(isset($this->current_company_id)){
            /** @var CompanyUser $companyUser */
            $companyUser = $this->teams()->where('companies.id', $this->current_company_id)->first()->pivot;

            if($companyUser->hasPermissionTo($ability)){
                return true;
            }

            // We still run through the gate on fail, as this will check for gate bypass. i.e. Super User
            return app(Gate::class)->forUser($this)->check('InvalidPermission');
        }

        return app(Gate::class)->forUser($this)->check($ability, $arguments);
    }
}
```

Now we can do something like this:

1. Create the role & permission

```
/** @var Role $ownerRoll */
$ownerRoll = Role::create(['name' => 'Owner']);

/** @var Permission $permission */
$permission = Permission::create([
    'name' => 'Create Company',
    'guard_name' => 'web',
]);

$ownerRoll->givePermissionTo($permission);
```

2. Create a new company with an owning user and then switch this company to that owner's active company.

```
public function store(CompanyStoreRequest $request)
{
    DB::transaction(function () use($request) {
        /** @var User $owner */
        $owner = User::findOrFail($request->user_id);

        /** @var Company $company */
        $company = $owner->companies()->create($request->validated());
        $company->addTeamMember($owner);

        $owner->assignRolesForCompany($company, 'Owner');
        $owner->switchCompanies($company);
    });

    return redirect()->back();
}
```

So this all works, my main concerns are that:

1. We are overwriting the can method. There may be other authorization methods/gate functions that are not caught.
2. We have 2 sets of model_permissions. The Auth user and the company user. I think I need to build in some checks to ensure that only the correct kinds of users can be assigned to the roles. At this stage, all administrator users would have permissions assigned to their auth user, while any users who own a company should only have permissions on the company user model